# How to display a "" when db returns null value

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to return data from a SQL-table with some null-values.  However, when I return null-values, I get strange dates like "1970-1-1".

Instead of strange dates, I would like to display "" if the value is null.

I am new and can't seem to fix this error with my code... How could I go about implementing fixing my bad-date problem?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
  $ship_date = $row['ship_date'];;
  $ship_date = date("m-d-Y", strtotime($ship_date));
?>
```

Comment: You can check `if (is_null($row['ship_date'])){$ship_date = "";}else{$ship_date = date("m-d-Y", strtotime($row['ship_date']));}`

Comment: It's easier to modify your query, replace `ship_date` with `COALESCE(ship_date, '')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good place to use conditional control statements like if-else.

**Try:**

```
$ship_date = $row['ship_date'];
if ($ship_date == NULL){
  $ship_date = "";
}
else {
  $ship_date = date("m-d-Y", strtotime($ship_date));
}
```